# How to get current member in a Razor macro

Tags: macros, umbraco

I have asked this question on the [Our Umbraco forums](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/razor/35083-How-to-get-current-member-in-a-Razor-macro), however I wanted to also increase my chances of getting a solution by posting the same question here.

The issue I have is that, inside a Razor macro, I'm unable to get the current `Member` who is accessing the site. I have tried the following methods:

- Calling Member.GetCurrentMember(), but this returns NULL.
- Calling Membership.GetUser(), but this returns NULL
- Calling UmbracoEnsuredPage.CurrentUser returned NULL;

Is there another way to get the current `Member` seeing how the above methods do not work in my case?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var m = Membership.GetUser();
```

That should work, just verified it myself on 4.7.1; it will return NULL if you are not logged in as a member, but when you log in it should get you what you want.

Comment: +1 Yup you're right. my blinking session must have been wiped without me realising it (IIS restart probably). Doh!

Answer (score 4):

Just a slight change from @E.J.Brennan if the NULL is an issue you can check if you are logged on before trying to GetUser():

```
if (umbraco.library.IsLoggedOn())
{
  m = Membership.GetUser();
}
```

Comment: Cheers for that tip, never knew about that one.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from v7 you can use the [MembershipHelper](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Querying/MemberShipHelper/)

```
@Members.CurrentUserName
@Members.GetCurrentMember()
@Members.GetCurrentMemberId()
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer. It's been a while since I last used Umbraco, but I can keep thins handy if member related API questions come up again for me.

Answer (score 0):

Now it's even easier, in the surfaceController you can use just one line:

```
var member = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MemberService.GetById(Members.GetCurrentMemberId());
```

If Members MembershipHElper isn't accessible:

```
var memberShipHelper = new MembershipHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);
var member = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MemberService.GetById(memberShipHelper.GetCurrentMemberId());
```